# Simplifying $\left(\nabla\vec{A}\right)\vec{B}$ to a more computationally efficient form

Tags: asymptotics, vector-analysis, vector-fields

If one wanted to calculate $\left(\nabla\vec{A}\right)^T\vec{B}$ and knew that $\vec{B}$ was a constant, they could just calculate $\nabla\left({\vec{A}}^T\vec{B}\right)$ instead. This is because
$$\nabla\left({\vec{A}}^T\vec{B}\right)=\left(\nabla\vec{A}\right)^T\vec{B}+\left(\nabla\vec{B}\right)^T\vec{A}$$
Where the vector gradient is defined by
$$\left(\nabla\vec{A}\right)_{ij}=\left(\frac{\partial A_i}{\partial x_j}\right)$$
The reason why they should calculate it that way instead is because $\nabla\left({\vec{A}}^T\vec{B}\right)$ is calculated in O(n) whereas $\left(\nabla\vec{A}\right)^T\vec{B}$ is calculated in O(n²). I need to calculate $\left(\nabla\vec{A}\right)\vec{B}$ instead, which will also take O(n²). Is there a way I can simplify the calculation? $\vec{B}$ is still a constant.

EDIT: I've determined that $\left(\nabla\vec{A}\right)\vec{B}=\nabla\cdot\left(\vec{B}{\vec{A}}^T\right)=\left(\vec{B}\cdot\nabla\right)\vec{A}$. Not really any easier to calculate to be honest. Starting to doubt a computationally simpler method exists.

Comment: What are you going to do with this quantity after? If you can just carry around $\nabla \vec{A}$ and $\vec{B}$ separately you'll only need $\mathcal{O}(n)$. Do the rest of your calculations simplify like that? Otherwise, you may as well ask whether there's a more efficient way of calculating $\vec{A}\vec{B}$, which I assume is some outer product like the Kronecker product. I don't think you can do a Kronecker product between two vectors faster than $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$ - eg https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/39961

Comment: @MarkViola I think the goal is to not use the transpose

Comment: @QuantumMechanic The quantity is added to another vector which is calculated in O(n). The resulting vector is then multiplied by an inverse matrix. The n✕n matrix $\nabla\vec{A}$ is calculated in O(n²) as is the subsequent matrix vector multiplication.